# Adding and editing select box in symfony

Tags: symfony, drop-down-menu, dropdownchoice

I am new to symfony. Trying to create an add and edit form with it. When I tried to add a select box in which the choice data is populated from database, but the select box shows only id as the value and name of option list

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
            ->add('category_id', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Category',
                    'choices'  => array(
                    $category)))
```

This is my controller portion

```
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Category</label>
                    {{ form_widget(form.category_id, {'attr' : { 'class':'form-control'}}) }}
              </div>
```

my output is

```
   <option value="id">id</option>
```

Please help me to display name too

```
 <option value="id">Name</option>
```

Comment: Who is `$category`?

Answer (score 0):

Just because data is populated from db. Then instead of ChoiceType::class change to EntityType::class

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('category_id', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Category',
                'choices'  => array(
                $category)))
```

check official doc [EntityType Field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage)